# How do I disambiguate mentions of a minor mode in a docstring?

Tags: doc-strings

The docstring of the following function doesn't make Emacs happy:

```
(defun foo-all-the-bars ()
  "Foo all the bars.
Starts by fooing some bars by enabling `prettify-symbols-mode',
then manually foos any remaining bars."
  (prettify-symbols-mode))
```

Checkdoc complains with the following message:

> Disambiguate prettify-symbols-mode by preceding w/ function,command,variable,option or symbol.

Which one should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any I would use "function" because the proper documentation of a minor mode is in its function docstring.

Personally I tend to ignore this particular checkdoc warning.

Answer (score 1):

One way to disambiguate:

```
(defun foo-all-the-bars ()
  "Foo all the bars.
Starts by fooing some bars by enabling the command `prettify-symbols-mode',
then manually foos any remaining bars."
  (prettify-symbols-mode))
```

Instead of `command`, you can use `function`, `variable`, `option`, or `symbol` as the `checkdoc` string suggests. In any case, this is not a lisp syntactic requirement but a grammar style suggested by `checkdoc` for doc strings.

Comment: Is that true? I thought that this prefix was used to decide what to target to use for the link in the docs, so it wouldn't be just grammar style.

Comment: Perhaps there are other incidental benefits.